# How can I get libcurl to return me dnsresolver used for connect call?

Tags: libcurl

I want to figure out which DNS resolver was used when making connect call to debug if the issue of

> "error code 6: resolution failed"

I tried to look up here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html ,
but there is no hint of how to get this info?

I presume it uses `getaddrinfo` system call at its base layer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get that exact info from a run-time libcurl. You can use [curl_version_info](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_version_info.html) to figure out which resolver backend it uses and then read the FAQ on further details:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_does_libcurl_resolve_host_na